# How can I check if Rhapsody 7.6.1 is installed on Windows XP with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, installed-applications, rhapsody

I'm trying to write a program that checks if IBM Rational Rhapsody 7.6.1 (or any other version) is installed, on a Windows XP 32-bit machine.

I'm using C++ in Visual Studio.